# Java - sorting objects in array alphabetically and numerically

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

I got an array of objects that have a name and a number. I want to sort them first by the number (from high to low). If two or more objects have the same number, these have to be sorted alphabetically. How can I do this in Java? (The objects have getters for both name and number)

Example Input:

```
Object1 - AAA - 5
Object2 - ABC - 5
Object3 - XAC - 6
Object4 - ZZZ - 3
```

Output

```
Object3 - XAC - 6
Object1 - AAA - 5
Object2 - ABC - 5
Object4 - ZZZ - 3
```

Comment: Hi @trsommer, have you tried anything by yourself :)

Comment: I know how to sort them numerically and sort them alphabetically, but I was not able to combine them to get the result I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a custom comparator. Given:

```
class Item {
   String id;
   int nr;

   // with associated getters and the like.
}
```

spruce it up to be a full class, using records or [Lombok's `@Value`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value).

Then:

```
Comparator<Item> comparator =
  Comparator
  .comparingInt(Item::getNr).reversed()
  .thenComparing(Item::getId);
```

Armed with this comparator, you can just invoke sort. If you have an array:

```
Item[] items = ...;
Arrays.sort(items, comparator);
```

If you have a list:

```
List<Item> list = ...;
list.sort(comparator);
```

NB: I suggest you use List, arrays are a bit annoying and low level.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, works perfectly